# HelloWorld WebAssembly compile in shared folder VirtualBox

Tags: webassembly

I'm trying to compile hello world program using emcc tool in the shared folder between host and VM VirtualBox target. When I'm using shared folder in target os I've got the error if I use not shared folder all is fine. Who can tell me why?

Program code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("hello, world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Command to compile:

```
$ emcc ../main.c
```

emcc version:

```
$ emcc -v
emcc (Emscripten gcc/clang-like replacement + linker emulating GNU ld) 3.1.28 (f11d6196dd4e8748a726f19895c859b40ff6a4f3)
clang version 16.0.0 (https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project ea4be70cea8509520db8638bb17bcd7b5d8d60ac)
Target: wasm32-unknown-emscripten
Thread model: posix
```

Python version:

```
$ python --version
Python 3.8.10
```

Files that are generated:

```
-rwxrwx--- 1 root systemd-coredump 13835 dec 13 08:44 a.out.wasm*
-rwxrwx--- 1 root systemd-coredump 13835 dec 13 08:44 a.out.wasm.tmp31770cd*
```

The error I've got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alex/hdd/repo/emsdk/upstream/emscripten/emcc.py", line 4309, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/contextlib.py", line 75, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/alex/hdd/repo/emsdk/upstream/emscripten/emcc.py", line 4302, in main
    ret = run(args)
  File "/home/alex/hdd/repo/emsdk/upstream/emscripten/emcc.py", line 1319, in run
    phase_post_link(options, state, wasm_target, wasm_target, target)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/contextlib.py", line 75, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/alex/hdd/repo/emsdk/upstream/emscripten/emcc.py", line 3022, in phase_post_link
    phase_emscript(options, in_wasm, wasm_target, memfile)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/contextlib.py", line 75, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/alex/hdd/repo/emsdk/upstream/emscripten/emcc.py", line 3052, in phase_emscript
    emscripten.run(in_wasm, wasm_target, final_js, memfile)
  File "/home/alex/hdd/repo/emsdk/upstream/emscripten/emscripten.py", line 893, in run
    emscript(in_wasm, out_wasm, outfile_js, memfile)
  File "/home/alex/hdd/repo/emsdk/upstream/emscripten/emscripten.py", line 318, in emscript
    metadata = finalize_wasm(in_wasm, out_wasm, memfile)
  File "/home/alex/hdd/repo/emsdk/upstream/emscripten/emscripten.py", line 525, in finalize_wasm
    metadata = get_metadata(infile, outfile, modify_wasm, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/contextlib.py", line 75, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/alex/hdd/repo/emsdk/upstream/emscripten/emscripten.py", line 451, in get_metadata
    metadata = extract_metadata.extract_metadata(infile)
  File "/home/alex/hdd/repo/emsdk/upstream/emscripten/tools/extract_metadata.py", line 303, in extract_metadata
    with webassembly.Module(filename) as module:
  File "/home/alex/hdd/repo/emsdk/upstream/emscripten/tools/webassembly.py", line 192, in __init__
    raise InvalidWasmError(f'{filename} is not a valid wasm file')
tools.webassembly.InvalidWasmError: a.out.wasm is not a valid wasm file
Exception ignored in: <function Module.__del__ at 0x7f45e8756dc0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alex/hdd/repo/emsdk/upstream/emscripten/tools/webassembly.py", line 196, in __del__
    assert not self.buf, '`__exit__` should have already been called, please use context manager'
AssertionError: `__exit__` should have already been called, please use context manager
```

Answer (score 0):

I've recently experienced this issue myself and through testing I have found it related to the shared folder system.

Specifying an emcc output within your shared folder will result with this error.

You can however still use emcc within your shared folder system, but the only solution I have found is to specify an output outside of it, then you can move the file back into the shared folder system.

```
emcc main.c -o /external_folder/main.out.wasm
mv /external_folder/main.out.wasm ./
```

This error may be related to the permissions or the way that virtualbox shares them, however I have not yet found a more apt solution than this.